# Disable "auto" scroll on multiscroll.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiscroll.js

I want to disable the "auto" scrolling on multiscroll.js plugin. (for those who don't know its a "split screen" js plugin)

[Here is a codepen.](http://codepen.io/leetech/pen/HALtI) I've managed to achieve this easily. But I don't want it to be, lets say, magnetic (I don't know how else I can describe it). [Here is](http://www.puma.com/actvrcvr/#/intro) what I'm trying to do . As you can see you can scroll normally the two split sections. They don't automatically "stick" together immediately after scroll.

Here is [multiscroll.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/multiscroll.js)

I've tried to use `normalScrollElements`, by adding classes to each section and then link them to `normalScrollElements` without luck.

```
jQuery('#multiscroll').multiscroll({
    sectionsColor: ['#2980b9', '#2ecc71', '#e74c3c',],
    normalScrollElements: '.sec1, .sec2, .sec3',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update April 2017

There's an extension that allows to turn each side within a section into a full-width section. Then it turns auto scrolling off so it scrolls like a normal site.

[Check it out here.](http://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll/extensions/responsive-expand.html) Just resize the viewport to see it working.

## Original answer

I'm afraid that what you want to achieve can not be done with multiScroll.js. It is not designed to work that way.

I personally find [the site you mention](http://www.puma.com/actvrcvr/#/intro) quite annoying when using it with a mouse wheel in a windows machine. Or even with a normal scroll bar, it is quite irritating not seeing the whole picture together as it is suppose to be and the automatic fit is not perfect at all.